# Is a flyback diode required for this relay?

Tags: relay

Regarding the relay RL1 input side below, I know that the flyback diode D1 below prevents high voltage spike at the collector of the Q1 during switch off:

[image]

The relay RL2 above is magnetized by the output of RL1. So my question is would the RL2 or the RL1 output require another flyback diode?

Comment: Depends on the voltage rating of RL1 contacts :-) Just add it.

Comment: Datasheet says "Switches 5A at 230VAC/30VDC" https://docs.rs-online.com/356b/0900766b80660fe5.pdf

Comment: The real question is: does your 5V regulator like back EMF? If not, then use a flyback diode.

Comment: @Lundin The voltage spike will occur at the switch contacts of RL1. And +5V is SMPS power supply output in my case.

Comment: It will pass through the contacts and hit the 5V plane.

Comment: @Lundin But wait in  his case what should be the direction of the flyback diode?

Comment: Always across the coil, cathode towards +, same as for any relay. There's nothing special with your circuit that will magically remove the EMF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a flyback diode you'll minimize the sparking at the contacts of RL1 and perhaps improve its life (depending on the characteristics of the RL2 coil and the RL1 contacts), and you'll reduce the EMI that might be a problem externally, or find its way back through RL1 coil etc. and cause (say) MCU upset.

The down side is that you'll slow the opening of the contacts on RL2 and may reduce its life noticeably. The life of relays is generally specified on the datasheets *without* the diode.

So, it's a design trade-off and the best choice depends on the details. As well as that binary choice there are other options such as an RC snubber (just a resistor and capacitor in series), a Zener diode + diode or bipolar TVS, a resistor + diode etc.

Comment: I found RL1 datasheet : https://docs.rs-online.com/356b/0900766b80660fe5.pdf

Comment: Is the reduced life of RL2 (when a flyback diode is added) due to the increased arcing of the contacts as they open more slowly?

Comment: @brhans Yes, it is.

Comment: Switching a 5V relay? Of unknown type? If it's less than 100mA coil, I think you can  leave the diode out, but that's just a guess of which is better.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany RL2 coil rated current is 120mA.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany For RL2 what should be the direction of the flyback diode? Like D1 or upside down?

Comment: Same as D1 so it is reverse-biased when the coil is energized. Otherwise it will fry very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not.  But it will reduce EMI and increase contact life of RL1.  An RC snubber could also be used (say 100R + 100nF).

Likewise, the "Line"-"Line" path might benefit from a snubber or MOV or something.  Depends.

Is it really a 5V coil?  What's the point of RL1 then?  (Are there other contacts not shown here?)  Also, why R2?